# mismatched input 'if' expecting 'end of line without line continuation' with if elif and else statements?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I'm using PineScript v3 but it says I have a** mismatched input 'if' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'** All of the If statements are closed a and none remain open and all have else statements.

However I have all the correct statements. Here is my code:

````
//@version=3

// Define variables
length = 20
stdDev = 2
error_range = 0.5
fastLength = 12
slowLength = 26
macdLength = 9
rsiLength = 14
a = 0

// Calculate the moving average
ma = sma(close, length)

// Calculate the upper and lower bands
upper = ma + stdDev * stddev(close, length)
lower = ma - stdDev * stddev(close, length)

// Calculate On Balance Volume
obv = 0
prevClose = close[1]
for i = 2 to bar_index
    if close[i] > prevClose[i]
        obv := obv + volume[i]
    else if close[i] < prevClose[i]
        obv := obv - volume[i]
    else
        obv := obv

// Calculate MACD
macd = ema(close, fastLength) - ema(close, slowLength)
signal = ema(macd, macdLength)

// Calculate RSI
rsi = rsi(close, rsiLength)

// Calculate Fibonacci retracements
fib_23_6 = fibonacci(high, low, close, 23.6)

// Define conditions for buy and sell signals
buy = crossover(obv, upper) and obv > upper + error_range and crossover(macd, signal) and rsi < 30 and close > fib_23_6
sell = crossunder(obv, lower) and obv < lower - error_range and crossunder(macd, signal) and rsi > 70 and close < fib_23_6

// Set variable a to positive or negative based on buy or sell signals
if (buy)
    a := abs(a)

else if (sell)
    a := -abs(a)

else
    a:=0```


It should just have gone through.
````

Answer (score 0):

The 4th version of Pine Script Language allows you to use “else if” syntax.

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#op_if

In v3 you can only use "if" or "else"